# laravel 8 array sorting issue

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

here i am getting data from 3 models banner , banner types and its positions (there is no issue with banner type model so i am skipping it )[the admin template is generated from quickadminpanel ]

my data structure looks like

banner

```
Schema::create('banners', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('banner_name')->unique();
            $table->string('banner_header');
            $table->string('banner_caption')->nullable();
            $table->string('banner_btn_txt');
            $table->string('banner_btn_link');
            $table->string('banner_btn_color');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

2021_01_15_000003_create_positions_table.php

```
Schema::create('positions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('position');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

2021_01_15_000019_add_relationship_fields_to_positions_table.php

```
Schema::table('positions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('banner_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('banner_id', 'banner_fk_2983258')->references('id')->on('banners');
        });
```

```
$banner = Banner::get();
$banner_types = BannerType::get();
$positions = Position::with(['banner'])->orderBy("position")->get();
$banner_array = array();
$banner_no_position = array();
foreach ($banner as $banner){
     if(Position::where('banner_id',$banner->id)->count() != 0){
            $banner_array = array($banner);
     }else{
            // print_r($banner);
            $banner_no_position = array($banner);
     }
}
```

what i am trying to do is separating the banners which has positioned and which has not positioned by creating 2 different arrays
the one called `$banner_array` is working smoothly but the other `$banner_no_position` is just showing the last object and discarding the other objects

for example i have created 4 banners and i have positioned just 2 then i get 2 objects in `$banner_array` and only 1 object in  `$banner_no_position` array but it should have 2 or more array since i have not positioned 2 banners

my blade looks like the https://pastebin.com/hwAqjZ7S and my complete controller looks like https://pastebin.com/LvvLPSNP its bit messy but i will beautify few functions later
The functions i am using from controllers are index and newPosition to read and to save data resp

banner model looks like https://pastebin.com/75nCdBvh
and position model looks like https://pastebin.com/vr7GPd8A

Comment: if you have a relationship from Banner to Position then you can use `has` and `doesntHave` to separate them, or you could use `withCount` and then separate them based on that with the help of the `partition` Collection method

Comment: the relationship it has is from position to banner ie return $this->belongsTo(Banner::class, 'banner_id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relationship setup you can use the relationship to help with this:

```
$banners = Banner::has('positions')->get();
$banners_without_positions = Banner::doesntHave('positions')->get();
```

Here we are using a query to return all Banners that have any Positions. Then we are doing another query to return all Banners that do not have any Positions.

Or you could use the `withCount` method to get a count of the relationship for every Banner then use the collection's `partition` method to break this into 2 different groups:

```
[$banners, $banners_without] = Banner::withCount('positions')
    ->get()
    ->partition(fn ($i) => $i->positions_count);
```

Here we are saying if the count of this relationship is a positive number (true) then sort it into the first set, if not (no positions) sort it into the second set. You can also do this by just eager loading `positions` (`with('positions')`) then doing a count on the relationship, `$i->positions->count()` but if you don't need the relationship loaded there is no need to load it and hydrate the models.

Adjust the naming of things as needed.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `has`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) `doesntHave`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) `withCount`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-partition) `partition`

Comment: i update the qustion and added the model to it but i will try this